# Can't create table throught a view with function inside mysql

Tags: mysql, select, view, insert

I created two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `prova` (
`id`  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`text`  varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
;

CREATE TABLE `prova2` (
`id2`  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`text2`  varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id2`)
)
;

insert into prova (text) values ('ffffff');
```

A function does a select on table one and inserts a row in table two only if the value of variable `@test` is set to 0:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_prova`()
 RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN

declare id_prova int ;
declare test int ;


    set @test = 1;
    set @id_prova = (select id from prova limit 1);

    if (@test = 0) THEN
        insert into prova2 (text2) values ('dddd');
    end if;

return @id_prova;

END;
```

then, I create a view that calls this function:

```
create view temp_prova as 
select  id,
            text, 
            get_prova() as prova
from prova
```

I want to create table 3 that contains the result of view:

```
CREATE TABLE zzz_prova  SELECT * FROM temp_prova;
```

but when I try to create table `zzz_prova` I get this error:

> [SQL]CREATE TABLE zzz_prova  SELECT * FROM temp_prova; [Err] 1746 -
>   Can't update table 'prova2' while 'zzz_prova' is being created.

Why does this error show up?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of MySQL are you running?

> [Changes in MySQL 5.6.2 (2011-04-11)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-2.html)
>
> - Incompatible Change; Replication: It is no longer possible to issue a
>     CREATE TABLE ... SELECT statement which changes any tables other than
>     the table being created. Any such statement is not executed and
>     instead fails with an error.
>
>   One consequence of this change is that FOR UPDATE may no longer be
>     used at all with the SELECT portion of a CREATE TABLE ... SELECT.
>
>   This means that, prior to upgrading from a previous release, you
>     should rewrite any CREATE TABLE ... SELECT statements that cause
>     changes in other tables so that the statements no longer do so.
>
>   This change also has implications for statement-based replication
>     between a MySQL 5.6 (or later slave) and a master running a previous
>     version of MySQL. In such a case, if a CREATE TABLE ... SELECT
>     statement on the master that causes changes in other tables succeeds
>     on the master, the statement nonetheless fails on the slave, causing
>     replication to stop. To keep this from happening, you should either
>     use row-based replication, or rewrite the offending statement before
>     running it on the master. (Bug #11749792, Bug #11745361, Bug #39804,
>     Bug #55876)
>
>   References: See also Bug #47899.

**UPDATE**

**MySQL 5.5**:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.5.47    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `f`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t1`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t2`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER |

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `f`()
    -> RETURNS INT
    -> BEGIN
    ->     INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES (1);
    ->     RETURN 1;
    -> END|
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CREATE TABLE `t2`(`c1` INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `t1` SELECT `f`() `c1`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `c1` FROM `t1`;
+------+
| c1   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `c1` FROM `t2`;
+------+
| c1   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**MySQL 5.6**:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 5.6.25          |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `f`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t1`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t2`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER |

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `f`()
    -> RETURNS INT
    -> BEGIN
    ->     INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES (1);
    ->     RETURN 1;
    -> END|
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CREATE TABLE `t2`(`c1` INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `t1` SELECT `f`() `c1`;
ERROR 1746 (HY000): Can't update table 't2' while 't1' is being created.
```

Comment: I'm using 5.6.19. Thank you for your comment. You solve my problem.